# Find out $f(n)$ where n is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, functions

Suppose I need a function $f(n)$ such that $f(n)$ is odd when $n=4,12,20,28...$ and even when $n=8,16,24,32...$. Then the answer would be $f(n)=\frac{n}{4}$.

Similarly, now suppose I need $f(n)$ such that $f(n)=1$ when $n=1,3$; $f(n)=3$ when $n=5,7$;    $f(n)=5$ when $n=9,11$;  $f(n)=7$ when $n=13,15$ and so on. What could f(n) in this case be?

I have tried the step function but that doesn't seem to work. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one?:
$$f(n)=2\left\lfloor\frac n4\right\rfloor+1$$

Comment: That's great. Could you also explain, how did you figure it out? By just trial and error, or by plotting or any other tool?

Comment: First, I noticed that you want odd numbers, that is, $2k+1$, beginning with $k=0$. Then, I only had to map $1$ and $3$ to $0$, $5$ and $7$ to $1$, etc, that is the same as dividing by $4$. (Integer division, I mean).

Comment: BTW, thanks for the comment. It made me think a bit more and I have improved the answer a little.